# iOS Storyboard: Vertical center all subviews whether there's 1 or 2 (dynamically determined)

Tags: ios, xcode

I think UIStackView is the way to go, but I've had constraint issues with that.

If a cell has 1 subview it should look like:

[image]

If a cell has 2 subviews it should look like:

[image]

I can do them separately in storyboard (if all cells have the same amount). First, with 2 subviews, I can add a heightless view in the middle and center it. And with 1 subview I just center it. But I'm trying to make it so storyboard will take care of them together, whether there's 1 or 2 subviews.

Note I've tried using a UIStackView, with Alignment: Center, and Distribution: Equal Centering, and with UIStackView constrained to its parent, but that leads to constraint issues. Also "Equal Centering" doesn't seem to center them.

Is there a way to have storyboard take care of both cases together?

Comment: Yup, UIStackView is definitely the simplest way to go here; it does _exactly_ what you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

Layout constraints for UIStackView
[image: Layout constraints for UIStackView]

Layout constraints for UIView(UILabel)
[image: Layout constraints for UIView(UILabel)]

Now you can hide any subview of UIStackView and all be stay centered.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at reading storyboard constraints from the image. What are the constraints?

Comment: UIStackView - center V and H; leading to superview 20. UIView - trailing and leading to superview 0, height 40 (whatever).

Comment: Thanks. It's still saying missing constraints for X position or Y position, but it does work as intended when I run it.